# Disable construction of non fully specialized template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, default-constructor, most-vexing-parse

I have this kind of structure for a template class.

My aim is to forbid creation of those class which not provide a full specialization:

```
class AbstractContainer
{
public:
   virtual ~AbstractContainer() = default;

   // declare here interface methods
};

template <class T>
class Container final : public AbstractContainer
{
public:
   Container() = delete;
};


template <>
class Container<int> : public AbstractContainer
{
public:
   Container() = default;

   explicit Container(const int& type) : AbstractContainer(), type_(type){}

private:
   int type_;
};
```

Everyhthing works fine

```
Container<int> a;     // it works
Container<int> a(5);  // it works
Container<char> a;    // does not compile
```

but I noticed it compiles for these case

```
Container<int> a(Container<char>());
Container<int> a(Container<CustomClass>());
```

How can I avoid this situation? I do want a copy constructor but not with the wrong type, ideally I would like to have the same issue of compile error (I could use an assert somewhere, but don't know how to set up it).

Comment: It begs the question, why have a default template at all?

Comment: @StoryTeller you mean why don't just remove the default template or why don't you use inheritance without template?

Comment: The later. You are in essence defining entire classes here. And don't even make use of the "default implementation" the primary can provide

Comment: @StoryTeller I could want to use and manage the default implementation in future and keep that door open

Comment: The door doesn't close if you go for regular classes either. But no matter, it's your code base. You probably have a clearer view than me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a [C++'s most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)  issue:

```
Container<int> a(Container<char>());
```

This is actually just a function declaration: It declares a function `a` that returns a `Container<int>` object and takes a pointer to a function that returns `Container<char>` and takes nothing.

Since it is just a function declaration, it does not instantiate `Container<char>` at all and, therefore you are not getting any error.

You could use brace syntax instead of parenthesis, i.e.:

```
Container<int> a{Container<char>()};
Container<int> b(Container<char>{});
Container<int> c{Container<char>{}};
```

The code above does declare three objects: `a`, `b` and `c`.

---

#### Getting a custom error when instantiating `Container<>`'s primary template

You could define the following template, `deferred_false`, as:

```
template<typename>
struct deferred_false {
    static constexpr auto value = false;
};
```

or simply as:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename> struct deferred_false: std::false_type{};
```

Then, place a `static_assert` that uses this `deferred_false<T>::value` in the definition of your class template :

```
template<class T>
class Container final : public AbstractContainer
{
   static_assert(deferred_false<T>::value, "Trying to instantiate Container<>");
};
```

This way, the assertion will fail at compile time when the primary template of `Container` is going to be instantiated, but won't fail when the primary template is not being instantiated, since the condition of the `static_assert` depends on the template parameter (i.e.: `T`).

That is, if there is no specialization of `Container` for `Foo` and you have:

```
Container<Foo> a;
```

You will get the following compile-time error:

> error: static assertion failed: Trying to instantiate `Container<>`

Comment: You may use `template <typename> struct deferred_false : std::false_type {};`

Comment: It is necessary for deferred_false to be a template function?

Comment: @Moia yes, else it makes the program illegal, no diagnostics required

Comment: Yes, it is necessary that the evaluation of `false` is deferred until the primary template is instantiated, otherwise the `static_assert` will fail even if you don't instantiate the template.